# How to change the recv() portion of a client to an Interrupt Service Routine?

Tags: c, interrupt, client-server

I currently have a client listening for packets in its own thread.  I was told to try to implement an ISR so that the packet received from the recv() call can be handled immediately, instead of waiting for that thread to get scheduled.

**EDIT:** this is in windows now, but it will ported to a DSP later.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Most likely, the solution is to change the thread's priority or configuration so it is scheduled immediately as a result of the existing ISR.

Comment: Without more info (like OS, etc.) this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

ISRs by definition run in kernel space. Unless you are in an embedded system without memory protection, you will need to add kernel code to your project. Furthermore, to reimplement `recv`, it will need to handle IP and TCP or UDP as necessary to extract the data from the ethernet packets.

The overhead of rescheduling and switching to a thread is minimal, and needs to happen anyway unless the packet is handled entirely in the kernel. Most operating systems have a highest-priority thread setting, sometimes called "real-time," which causes user space code to run with minimal delay after the driver receives data. This is often used for audio/video I/O as well as networking.

Comment: I dont want to re-implement recv().  What I am trying to do is implement an ISR that gets triggered when the recv() function returns.  I am sorry for not being clear on the original question.

Comment: @emge: An ISR such as this gets triggered by an external signal to the microprocessor. If `recv` has returned already, the ISR has done is job and already switched to your thread. Your kernel might offer a way to filter data before it gets to `recv` or call an alternate `recv` directly in kernel space, but again without knowing your platform there is nothing I can do to help.

Comment: this is in windows now, but it will ported to a DSP later